# Subtract the sum of multiple values from a value in a different dataset across multiple groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two related datasets, one contains the counts and grand totals of different types of fruits, including citrus fruits, and the other contains counts of just citrus fruits. Both datasets contain data from the same regions and I need to subtract the numbers of citrus fruits in df2 from df1, per region.

The data:

```
set.seed(123)

region1 <- as.factor(rep(c('north', 'north-east', 'east', 'south-east', 'south', 
                      'south-west', 'west', 'north-west', 'centre', 'islands'),
                      each = 6))
fruit <- as.factor(rep(c('2. citrus', '3. pear and orange', '5. bananas', 
                         '1. kiwi and lemon', '6. plums', '4. apple and lime'), 10))
count1 <- as.integer(signif(rnorm(60, mean = 2000, sd = 500)), 1)
gtotal1 <- as.numeric(round(rnorm(60, mean = 20000, sd = 5000)), 0)
df1 <- data.frame(region1, fruit, count1, gtotal1)

region2 <- as.factor(rep(c('north', 'north-east', 'east', 'south-east', 'south', 
                          'south-west', 'west', 'north-west', 'centre', 
                          'islands'),
                        each = 7))
citrus <- as.factor(rep(c('6. lisbon (lemon)', '24. easy p. (orange)', '25. navel (orange)', 
                          '37. blood (orange)', '37. tang. (orange)', '43. mand. (orange)',
                          '46. key (lime)'), 10))
count2 <- as.integer(signif(rnorm(70, mean = 2000, sd = 500)), 1)
gtotal2 <- as.numeric(round(rnorm(70, mean = 20000, sd = 5000)), 0)
df2 <- data.frame(region2, citrus, count2, gtotal2)
```

In df1, the counts and gtotals of different citrus fruits were included with other kinds of fruits (e.g. kiwis and lemons), the "citrus" category was created via other means to give them their own category, but the values of the different citrus fruits are still included in the other paired categories. This issue is present for all 10 regions.

df2 contains the counts of these citrus fruits within the paired df1 categories, per region. I need to subtract the total number of lemons, oranges, and limes in df2 from their categories in df1 for each region.

This situation and data is synthetic, so ignore any errors in the values given. I need to do this for the count and gtotal columns.

Here are the two datasets:

```
df1                                              df2
      region1             fruit count1 gtotal1 |       region2             citrus count2 gtotal2
1       north         2. citrus   1719   21898 |       north     6. lisbon (lemon)   2058   21072
2       north 3. pear and orange  1884   17488 |       north  24. easy p. (orange)   1526   18377
3       north        5. bananas   2779   18334 |       north    25. navel (orange)   1754   20473
4       north 1. kiwi and lemon   2035   14907 |       north    37. blood (orange)   1871   15523
5       north          6. plums   2064   14641 |       north    38. tang. (orange)   2921   13446
6       north  4. apple and lime  2857   21518 |       north    43. mand. (orange)   1674   29986
7  north-east         2. citrus   2230   22241 |       north        46. key (lime)   2117   23004
8  north-east 3. pear and orange  1367   20265 |  north-east     6. lisbon (lemon)   2038   13744
9  north-east        5. bananas   1656   24611 |  north-east  24. easy p. (orange)   1519   16944
10 north-east 1. kiwi and lemon   1777   30250 |  north-east    25. navel (orange)   1964   14073
11 north-east          6. plums   2612   17545 |  north-east    37. blood (orange)   2722   30994
12 north-east  4. apple and lime  2179    8454 |  north-east    38. tang. (orange)   2225   26562
13       east         2. citrus   2200   25029 |  north-east    43. mand. (orange)   2020   18674
14       east 3. pear and orange  2055   16454 |  north-east        46. key (lime)   1788   22716
15       east        5. bananas   1722   16560 |        east     6. lisbon (lemon)    973   17928
...
```

And here is what I would like to obtain:

```
df3
        region             fruit count gtotal 
1       north         2. citrus   1719   21898 
2       north 3. pear and orange -7862  -80317 
3       north        5. bananas   2779   18334 
4       north 1. kiwi and lemon    -23   -6165
5       north          6. plums   2064   14641 
6       north 4. apple and lime    740   -1486
7  north-east         2. citrus   2230   22241 
8  north-east 3. pear and orange -9083  -86982  
9  north-east        5. bananas   1656   24611 
10 north-east  1. kiwi and lemon  -261   16506
11 north-east          6. plums   2612   17545 
12 north-east 4. apple and lime    391  -14262 
13       east         2. citrus   2200   25029 
14       east 3. pear and orange -8380  -82234
15       east        5. bananas   1722   16560 
...
```

I know how to do this manually, by splitting the data by region and doing subtractions using base R commands, but this would be time consuming I am sure there is a better way to do this using `dplyr` or `ifelse()` statements, and I would like to learn this for future issues.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### New Answer

From what I'm gathering, the cols that you want to compare in your two datasets (df1$fruit, df2$citrus), don't have any identifying traits to match them. Therefore, I would recommend manually creating a mapping table so you can link everything up properly. I created a `fruit_map` df here.

Continuing on - the process is actually a bit more straight forward than before where you use the fruit_map table to aggregate your citrus types by `fruit_grp`.

I don't see value in manually aggregating every type like you're suggesting. That can be prone to errors, follows poor coding techniques, difficult to read etc.

Hopefully, this is more applicable for your use case.

```
# Create relationship between fruit and citrus
fruit_map = data.frame(
  fruit_grp = as.factor(c("1. kiwi and lemon",rep("3. pear and orange",5),"4. apple and lime")),
  citrus = as.factor(c("6. lisbon (lemon)","24. easy p. (orange)","25. navel (orange)","37. blood (orange)","37. tang. (orange)","43. mand. (orange)","46. key (lime)"))
)

df2_by_grp = df2 %>%
  left_join(fruit_map, by = "citrus") %>%
  group_by(region2, fruit_grp) %>%
  summarise(across(c(count2, gtotal2), ~ sum(., na.rm = T))) %>%
  rename("fruit" = "fruit_grp")

agg_dt = df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2_by_grp, by = c("region1" = "region2", "fruit")) %>%
  mutate(count1 = count1 - count2, gtotal1 = gtotal1 - gtotal2) %>%
  select(region1:gtotal1)

df3 = df1 %>%
  rows_update(agg_dt, by = c("region1", "fruit")) %>%
  rename_with(~ gsub("1$", "", .x)) # update col names
```

#### Old Answer

Here's a possible solution.

We first create `citrus_cat` which only keeps the citrus name and not its' type. e.g. "lemon (lisbon)" -> "lemon".

Then group by `region2` and `citrus_cat` to get the sum of `count2` and `gtotal2` for those group pairings.

Next, we left join the new `df2` to the original `df1` and filter where `citrus_cat` exists in `fruit`. Here is where we subtract our total amounts found in `df2` from `df1`.

Lastly, since there are items present in df1 that did not have a match in the new aggregated table. We use `row_update` to only update the rows were there was a match.

Let me know if you have any questions!

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df2_by_grp = df2 %>%
  mutate(citrus_cat = word(citrus, 2)) %>% #extract second word
  group_by(region2, citrus_cat) %>%
  summarise(across(c(count2, gtotal2), ~ sum(., na.rm = T)))

agg_dt = df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2_by_grp, by = c("region1" = "region2")) %>%
  mutate(fruit = as.character(fruit)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(str_detect(fruit, citrus_cat)) %>%
  mutate(count1 = count1 - count2, gtotal1 = gtotal1 - gtotal2) %>%
  select(region1:gtotal1)

df3 = df1 %>%
  rows_update(agg_dt, by = c("region1", "fruit")) %>%
  rename_with(~ gsub("1$", "", .x)) # update col names
```

```
> df3

       region              fruit count gtotal
1       north          2. citrus  1719  21898
2       north 3. pear and orange -7862 -80317
3       north         5. bananas  2779  18334
4       north  1. kiwi and lemon   -23  -6165
5       north           6. plums  2064  14641
6       north  4. apple and lime   740  -1486
7  north-east          2. citrus  2230  22241
8  north-east 3. pear and orange -9083 -86982
9  north-east         5. bananas  1656  24611
10 north-east  1. kiwi and lemon  -261  16506
11 north-east           6. plums  2612  17545
12 north-east  4. apple and lime   391 -14262
13       east          2. citrus  2200  25029
14       east 3. pear and orange -8380 -82234
15       east         5. bananas  1722  16560
16       east  1. kiwi and lemon  1920   7200
17       east           6. plums  2248  18576
18       east  4. apple and lime -1334  -6700
...
```

Comment: Can you share data that is more representative of your actual dataset? There should be a way without dozens of ifelse statements. Also I thought you wanted to subtract the sum of the categories by region in df2 from df1. In your comment it looks like you're adding them.

Comment: The edit to my question adds the same numbers as the factors in my dataset, is there a way to do your method by just using the numbers?

Comment: My mistake (cant edit): this is an interesting way to approach it and I appreciate it! Unfortunately in my actual dataset this is not possible as the "fruit" categories I'm trying to add to do not contain the same names as the "citrus". Is there a way to do this by specifying the full citrus names that go into each fruit types in df1? E.g. along the lines of `group_by(region) %>% df1$count1["pears and oranges"] <- df1$count1["pears and oranges"] - df2$count2[orange (easy p.)] + df2$count2[orange (navel)] + df2$count2[orange (blood)] + etc`. Maybe `case_when()` or `ifelse()` could be used?

Comment: @Rlearn - it's still unclear to me since your expected output does not have the prefixed numbers in the fruit col. However, I made a minor change such that it will work with the numbers prefixed to the category. Does the latest update yield the result you want?

Comment: sorry I forgot to change those ones, I have updated my outputs. I have also changed the format of the citrus fruits in df2, I think this method would work in my dataset if it could use something other than the type of citrus like yours does (i.e. not lemon, orange, etc.). It would work best if I could manually assign the counts and gtotals for each type of citrus to their respective fruit in df1 like in my above comment, is it possible like this?

Comment: new answer worked a treat after I made it fit my data. Many thanks for all your work, its really appreciated. While the output is exactly what I want, I get this message on your third chunk to create `df2_by_grp` - `'summarise()' has grouped output by 'region2'. You can override using the '.groups' argument.` - does this indicate that other groups given after the first in `group_by()` are ignored?

Comment: Correct, if you run `?summarise`. It will give you more context. I didn't include the `.groups` arg so it's letting you know that it's being grouped by `region2`. `fruit_grp` is excluded since the result ends up being 1 row per group. e..g 1 row per region2 and fruit_grp. So keeping fruit_grp as a grouping var is unnecessary.